# Can someone explain to me what the 1s catching problem is in the Master Slave Flip Flop?

Tags: flipflop

I have read the explanation in my textbook but I feel that they are too complex and no matter how much I try to understand it I don't seem to get what the difference is when the 1s catching occurs. I have attached a picture where I got out of the book and I circled the part that it refers to as the 1s catching problem, but I don't see anything wrong with it.. It looks normal to me. Can someone show me what it is "supposed" to do at the 1s catching area? I just don't see anything wrong with it....

[image]

Comment: A set followed by a reset within the same clock cycle doesn't change the output, since the set is negated before the next falling edge of the clock. You lose both the set and reset.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Let me translate it into an answer so I can give more detail...

Comment: Can you post a schematic of the flip-flop?

Answer (score 3):

When you set or reset the flip flop the results of that set or reset are seen only when the clock signal transitions from a HIGH to a LOW level (known as a "falling edge").  This can be seen at about 80ns where the falling Q coincides with the falling C.

When you set S it first sets Y before it propagates out to Q on a falling C.  When you set R it resets Y, which then propagates out to Q on the falling C.

If Y is set and then immediately reset before the next falling C the change in Y will never be reflected in Q.  So if you set S and then, before the following falling C set R, the output Q will never change, so those two events of setting and resetting are "lost" in the internals of the flip-flop, and you never know they have happened.

In the waveform you have, Y would have to be HIGH at 140ns in order for Q to react to the S at ~125ns, but the R at ~130ns has cancelled it out before you could see it.